# Apply onBlur to form elements but not to the reset button

Tags: reactjs, forms, onblur

I'm working with a form that has onBlur defined on it. I would now like to add a button within the form to reset it. But when I added the button, it attached the onBlur to it, so now clicking the button doesn't work and it only executes when I tab away from the button.

Here's a very condensed version of my code:

```
<form onBlur={handleBlur} onReset={onClear}>
  <label>
    Input1
    <input type="text"/>
  </label>
  <label>
    Input2
    <input type="text"/>
  </label>
  <button type="reset">Reset</button>
</form>
```

I imagine one solution would be to attach the onBlur to each input, instead of on the `<form>`, but that would be a large refactor based on the code I haven't shown. So I am wondering if there is a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to stop the propagation of blur event from button element to form element. This is a javascript concept called event propagation. Basically every event will propagate from their child to parent. So u can prevent it using `event.stopPropagation()`

```
<form onBlur={handleBlur} onReset={onClear}>
  <label>
    Input1
    <input type="text" />
  </label>
  <label>
    Input2
    <input type="text" />
  </label>
  <button onBlur={(e) => e.stopPropagation()} type="reset">
    Reset
  </button>
</form>;
```